# Is there Global variables in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In java and C++ we could store a variable globally and access its value from any where in the project.
Say, i am inside a class called `Residence` and i am saving the `residenceNumber` which is a `INT` to a global variable called `houseNumberGlobalVariable`.

Now, i could access  `houseNumberGlobalVariable` from any class in the project. In a similar fashion, is there a Global variable in `EXTJS` that i could use.

I need to set a value from one class and access it from another. What is the equivalent in EXT JS. I don't think there's a global variable concept in EXTJS, but what is the equivalent in it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare a variable in `app.js` it will act as global variable.

```
var globalVar;
```

You can add anything into that like

```
globalVar.myStore = yourStore;
```

Comment: It will be easy to keep all global2 variables in one class. So can i even store a `view`,`store` using @sha's approach ?

Comment: yes, but i didn't tried! i usually add all to same var. like globalVar.myView, globalVar.myCtl. i dont know whats the benfit using class here.

Comment: How do i access `store` which i stored in `globalvar.mystore` ? Is it var accessstore = globalvar.mystore; ??

Comment: I have set globalvar in app.js. now i am trying to set values to it from the controller as `globalvar.id=1`. then i get `globalvar.id is not defined`. When i just set `globalvar=1` and try to access it else where as `var id=globalvar` then it works. Can you explain how you are setting values like `globalvar.store=mystore` ?

Comment: i missed it, after declaring , i made that as an array. globalVar= {};

Comment: If you would like to add some properties to it later, don't forget to assign it an empty object: `var globalVar = {}` and to avoid collisions, maybe do something like: `var globalVar = globalVar || {};`

Answer (score 21):

Create a special class and put all your `global` variables there.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.global.Vars', {
    singleton: true,
    ....   
    houseNumberGlobalVariable: undefined

});
```

This way if you need access for it anywhere in the code just use `MyApp.global.Vars.houseNumberGlobalVariable`

Comment: Where should i create this file ? in `View` ?

Comment: I would advise to create a separate file for the class, or put it inside main `app.js`.

Comment: This is the best way to declare global variables with ExtJS. Too bad wasn't set as Answer.

Comment: When I create a new js for this, I can't see it or access it.. do I need to declare it somewhere?

Comment: Need to tie up where used
`requires: [
        'TestApp.global.Links',
    ],`

Answer (score 3):

Based on your Application you can declare your global variable.

**Scenario 1 : Declare inside the config**

If you are going to use getter/setter methods (i.e change the variable frequently then go for config based)

*Declaring the Appconstants*

```
Ext.define('Practice.utilities.AppConstants', {
    alias: 'widget.AppConstants',
    config: {
        mainVarTest: 'mainVarTest',
    },
    testvar: 'Testing value',
    foo: 'bar',
    meh: 42,
    constructor: function(options) {
        this.initConfig(options);
    }
});
```

*Calling the variable*

```
var AppConstants = Ext.widget("AppConstants"); 
console.log(AppConstants.getMainVarTest());
```

---

**Scenario 2 : Declare inside Singleton class**

If your application needs global variable but it wont be alter any more inside the app. This class help to load the constant variable only once. (i.e you are not going changing the variable). This type is suits for your application

*Declaring*

```
Ext.define('Practice.utilities.AppConstants', {
    alias: 'widget.AppConstants',
    singleton: true,
    testvar: 'Testing value',
    foo: 'bar',
    meh: 42,
});
```

*Calling*

```
var AppConstant=Practice.utilities.AppConstants;
console.log(AppConstant.foo);
```

---

**Scenario 3 : Declare as Statics**

Statics is static variable (exactly same as java). Advantage of using static variable is the life time of variable is indefinite longer period until explicitly cleared.

```
Ext.define("Practice.utilities.AppConstants", {
     statics: {
         mainVarTest: 'mainVarTest'
     },
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the one thing missing here was a solution from the Sencha Architect program on how to create a global variable.

Go to your "Application" node on the project Inspector.  Next click in the Configs search/Filter box, this is not only for searching but for creating config entries too.  When you first look at this box it will have a Smokey pre-filled text of `Filter Configs...` .

Enter your global variable name and you will notice nothing is found in the list below, **(if the value is found in the config list then you already have this variable or your using a keyword)**.  To the right of the text box and the lock icon is an "Add" button.  Click the "Add" button to add your global variable into the application.

So lets say we have created the `Foo` variable at this point.  You will now see an entry in your config list.   To the left of this entry is an ellipses button, this is currently designating that the new variable we created is a String.  Click the button and change it to something different like a 'Number' field.   Enter a value for this new variable and your now done, you have a global variable.

So how do you access this newly created variable?  here is a sample bit of code stuffing the global into a local variable to be used.

```
var bar= MyApp.app.Foo;
```

The 'MyApp' reference is the Application `name` config setting for the application you are creating.  You can find this same value in the config settings of the Application node by filtering on `name`.

Answer (score 0):

var globalVar = {}; add in your app.js file, its working fine